# regexp in perl fails

Tags: regex, perl

Why is this failing?

```
WGroleau@MBP Chords % perl -p -i -e '(Trinidad|Donoso|Clifton|Frincke|Little|Church|Antonio) XYZ :\1\t:g;' *txt 
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ") XYZ"
    (Missing operator before XYZ?)
```

I have used this syntax many times in the past without this error (as far as I can remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you test:

```
perl -i -pe 's:(Trinidad|Donoso|Clifton|Frincke|Little|Church|Antonio) XYZ :$1\t:g' *txt
```

You missed the first part of substitution:

```
s:
```

And in perl, the captured group is `$1`, not `\1` (maybe can work in both cases).

Comment: (face palm!) — but the backslash has always worked and still does

Comment: This is not Perl's syntax, but can work.